# copy table from localhost to remote server?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I  copy a table from remote database to local  using following code

```
INSERT INTO manifest_status select * from 
dblink('host=1.2.3.4
 user=bn_openerp
 password=12345678
 dbname=Bodywears', 'select * FROM manifest_status') t1(
       id int,
  manifest_no character varying,
  tracking_number character varying,
  order_number character varying,
  status character varying,
  pos character varying
 );
```

It is working fine ,

my application change the data in table that is locally store .

**now i want to upload the table on remote server on host = 1.2.3.4**

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 case:

First case: There are no activity on your remote server. I mean your remote server don't update/insert/delete any data on "manifest_status" table. 
If so, you can delete that table on your remote server and then copy from local to your server. Please don't forget backup that tablet.

Second case: That table was updated/inserted/deleted. I think you have to do migration by manually. That mean you have to compare what's different between local and your remote data.

Comment: my server just upload the csv file into table .  and how can i copy from local to server ?

Answer (score 0):

```
createdb -U postgres -h 1.2.3.4 restored_mydb
pg_dump -U postgres mydb | ssh 1.2.3.4 "psql -d restored_mydb -U postgres"
```

Answer (score -1):

You should export the data on your local by CSV format file.

Please use this command:

```
COPY manifest_status TO '/tmp/manifest_status.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Please read the Postgres manual here @ http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html